# Button on click works only in console, not from UI when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that am binding to click event like the code below:

```
jQuery(function(){
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
  //code here
})}
```

When I click the button in browser, it doesn't execute my code. But when I open developer tools and type: `$("#btnSubmit")[0].click()`, it executes my code.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: The id of the element in your Html is btnSubmit? It fires because jQuery added a listener for when that event is fired besides the element in the html exists or not

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, yes the #btnSubmit exists in my html. it can be executed calling the button event, but when the mouse click on the button doesn't work?

Comment: The ID has to be without the #, just pointing obvious things, just in case. Can you show me the html?

Comment: Anyways, the code that you provided misses a curly brace and a parenthesis 

http://jsbin.com/kafehobese/edit?html,js,output

Comment: here is my html: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>`

Comment: Check out the answer that I provided, I also added the jsbin working

Comment: Sorry I missed the ) in my code sample here., but it exists already in my code.

Comment: Could you please try to replicate your same error in jsbin or plunkr? Or give me your html and jquery files to check out the problem?

Comment: There is no error as I mentioned. The code just doesn't execute.

Comment: Okay, can you please provide us your html and javascript file? Because we already provided jsbin and code examples working with  the html and javascript snippets that you provided

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this [code](http://jsbin.com/kafehobese/edit?html,js,output)?

```
jQuery(function(){
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
  console.log("hello");
});
});
```

Remember that in your html you need a button like this one

```
  <button id="btnSubmit"></button>
```

Comment: Yes, I already have the html: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>`  similar javascript as yours except for the console.log

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/codeforwin/yj9m6mLv/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
//do stuff here
});
```

Comment: it caused same result